# Adding JTextFields hard code free

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to write code for a program that will give users a hardcoded amount of JTextFields from top to bottom, with an option to add additional JTextFields. I have to retrieve user imported data from each JTextField afterwards. How do I do this?
All JTextFields are added to a JPanel.

Comment: well I would recommend creating a arraylist of the hardcoded `JTextField`s and than add any newly create textfields to the arraylist. then simply iterate the list and get each ones text or whatever when needed

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
    ArrayList<JTextField> list = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    //add all the hardcoded JTextFields to this list
    //b is a button which the user clicks to add extra TextFields
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JTextField a = new JTextField();
            panel.add(a);//panel is the existing panel
            list.add(a);
        }
    });
}
```

So with the help of 'list' you can later retrieve all the text fields

Comment: @user1840352 Please upvote and accept if the response is alright

Comment: How do I add code blocks, I want to show you what I did, but I can't figure it out.